# Bug onChange currentTime react-native-video-processing

Tags: react-native, video-player

I'm trying update on screen the current time, but it seems there is a bug, sometimes the `nativeEvent.currentTime` is repeating the last currentTime, or even don't go to the total duration, it end before.

For example, I recorded a video with duration of 6 seconds but its loggin like this:

[image: console result]

```
<VideoPlayer
  ref={ref => this.videoPlayerRef = ref}
  replay={true}
  play={this.state.playing}
  source={this.props.src}
  style={styles.player}
  onChange={({ nativeEvent }) => {
      console.log(nativeEvent.currentTime)
      this.setState({
        currentTimeSec:nativeEvent.currentTime})
    }
  }
  resizeMode={VideoPlayer.Constants.resizeMode.CONTAIN}/>
```

Comment: is it always the last second that's repeated?

Comment: 0->5 = 6... no?

Comment: @ChrisGeirman no is not happening always